# jquery load if iframe doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, iframe

Once i have clicked once on both items of the li(Google & Bing) i have created the iframes and i can do a search.

Now how would i do when i click again on the li to check if the iframe is already there so i don't reload the search?
Does that make sense?

```
<HTML> 
    <HEAD> 
    <TITLE></TITLE> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js "></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    iframe {width: 100%;height: 100%;max-width: 850px;min-height: 890px;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: auto;}
    </style>
    </HEAD> 

    <body> 
                <div id="search_engines" class="tabs">  

     <ul>
                  <li><a href="#google" onclick="googleLoad();">Google</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#bing" onclick="bingLoad();">Bing</a></li>

          </ul>


        <div id="google">

            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="googleLoad();" style="text-decoration: none" class="">New search</a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function googleLoad() {
            $("#googleIframe").html('<iframe id="googleLoad" frameborder="0" src="http:www.google.com"></iframe>'); 

            }
            </script>
            <div id="googleIframe"> 
            <!--Iframe goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>  

            <div id="bing">

            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="bingLoad();" style="text-decoration: none" class="">New search</a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function bingLoad() {
            $("#bingIframe").html('<iframe id="bingLoad" frameborder="0" src="http:www.bing.com"></iframe>'); 

            }
            </script>
            <div id="bingIframe">   
            <!--Iframe goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>

    </body> 

    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest and semantic way to go about it is to attach the click event via the jQuery `.one()` function (instead of an inline `onclick=` declaration). That way, your function executes after the click, and subsequent clicks won't trigger the load procedure again.

```
<a id="myGoogleLink">Google</a>
```

then bind that with

```
$('#myGoogleLink').one('click', function(){
    $('#googleIFrame').html("BLAH");
});
```

Now, if you were toggling between the Google and the Bing IFRAMEs, that's a whole different situation altogether.

Comment: I actually like this answer more than mine. Didn't know about the .one method. +1

Comment: @InfernalBadger ~ neither did I a week ago. :D

Comment: can you please give a concrete example?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example using Richards code - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/wCFLD/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this check to your code:

```
function googleLoad() {
    if(!$('#googleLoad').length) {
        $("#googleIframe").html('<iframe id="googleLoad" frameborder="0" src="http:www.google.com"></iframe>'); 
    }
}

function bingLoad() {
    if (!$('#bingLoad').length) {
        $("#bingIframe").html('<iframe id="bingLoad" frameborder="0" src="http:www.bing.com"></iframe>'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the idea but i want to be able to click on new search and reload the iframe :)

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that link. I recommend you use Richard's answer. Then you can bind using .one() for the #google and #bing links and .bind() for the new search.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
if($('#googleLoad').length > 0) {
  // iframe with id googleLoad exists
}
```